# Mathematica: Extract Co-ordinates of a Plot for which I do not know the Equation of

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

GIven a 2D plot in Mathematica, if you keep clicking the graph, a sequence of co-ordinates of that graph are shown. I'd like to extract the x and y co-ordinates of ALL of these points, WITHOUT using the "Get Coordinates" tool (which only extracts one co-ordinate at a time, which is both inaccurate and laborious). An additional constraint is that the equation of the plot is UNKNOWN (I found a graph produced by Wolfram Alpha, the equation of which is unknown to me. If I can simply extract the co-ordinates, I can fit a spline through those co-ordinates, thereby getting the equation of the graph). Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14222/getting-a-list-of-accurate-coordinates-from-a-plot

Comment: The solutions given here work on the basis that they know what the equation of the graph is. The problem I have is that I DO NOT know the equation of the graph.

Comment: How do you get the plot from wolfram alpha into mathematica?

Comment: Download them in .nb format (using a free 7 day subscription lol), and simply open in mathematica

Comment: The last answer in that link should do what you want.  Read down to the part  where you copy/past the plot graphic into an expression.  If that fails you should ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com.   As an aside the standard atmosphere package is built in to mathematica and quite easy to use.  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/StandardAtmosphere/guide/StandardAtmospherePackage.html

Comment: Here is a solution that I posted earlier at the Mathematica site:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167483/55694

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done in Mathematica 9.

First obtain the chart.

```
chart = WolframAlpha["density vs altitude of heterosphere",
  {{"EntrainedDensityPlot:AtmosphericLayers", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]

Extract the data section.  The x-axis is scaled according to the tick specification.

```
data = chart[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This is the content of the tick specification :-

```
ticksposition = Position[chart, Ticks];
ticks = Last@chart[[Sequence @@ Most[First@ticksposition]]];
Take[First@ticks, 5][[All, 1]]
```

> {-25.328436022934504, -18.420680743952367, -11.512925464970229`, 
>   -4.605170185988091, 2.302585092994046}

The numbers above relate to the following tick labels :-

```
{10^-11, 10^-8, 10^-5, 0.01, 10};
```

The line data is show below.  The x values can be rescaled according to the ticks.

```
data
```

> {{7.56584506772668,-5.},{7.522454313212941,-4.5},{7.4785653196771396,-4.},{7.4342573821331355,-3.5},{7.38950218524746,-3.},{7.344266755495627,-2.5},{7.2985804103507865,-2.},{7.25233739856673,-1.5},{7.205635176410364,-1.},{7.158436173289435,-0.5},{7.110696122978827,0.},{7.062448668658617,0.5},{7.0136456542395695,1.},{6.964230125910116,1.5},{6.91433359434226,2.},{6.863751143484082,2.5},{6.812620083867098,3.},{6.760878083121377,3.5},{6.708511342992233,4.},{6.655491829094075,4.5},{6.601814187258075,5.},{6.547459502017843,5.5},{6.4924064877997925,6.},{6.436647039879506,6.5},{6.380156434630315,7.},{6.32290629486736,7.5},{6.264901893476659,8.},{6.206091938653852,8.5},{6.1464577290734805,9.},{6.086001700931971,9.5},{6.0246816979681785,10.},{5.962473333757384,10.5},{5.899349258200177,11.},{5.821358081393286,11.5},{5.7428108616236795,12.},{5.664279054878501,12.5},{5.585749407744609,13.},{5.507199708509977,13.5},{5.42873140526997,14.},{5.350245459408396,14.5},{5.2717680313145,15.},{5.114815113005919,16.},{4.957937505095806,17.},{4.801148069229532,18.},{4.6443908991413725,19.},{4.487624622133048,20.},{4.326976291408619,21.},{4.16682025054415,22.},{4.007442270191581,23.},{3.848827581930999,24.},{3.6909772521960824,25.},{3.533890923387621,26.},{3.3775192543075785,27.},{3.221911213411722,28.},{3.0670291554360247,29.},{2.9128939952449864,30.},{2.7595034826911258,31.},{2.606755482950629,32.},{2.4486747988659405,33.},{2.2912612192626023,34.},{2.1357509841344284,35.},{1.9820905307957144,36.},{1.680194560884901,38.},{1.3852187828929574,40.},{1.096877451374393,42.},{0.8148779691310925,44.},{0.5389464994826453,46.},{0.27512860638016096,48.},{0.02654455522211221,50.},{-0.21614311166946532,52.},{-0.44783517527478434,54.},{-0.6842865521277486,56.},{-0.9256594818782552,58.},{-1.1722157727127442,60.},{-1.8127175638195325,65.},{-2.490977037365282,70.},{-3.220852777752422,75.},{-3.992257398138752,80.},{-4.801233732898559,85.},{-4.884341907755072,85.5},{-4.967863202252387,86.},{-5.6792850030558135,90.},{-6.576295584184468,95.},{-7.486859743501422,100.},{-9.239975177105872,110.},{-10.71451777375279,120.},{-11.71724726204385,130.},{-12.472384692245763,140.},{-13.085067592660632,150.},{-13.606060333782066,160.},{-14.062050687084879,170.},{-14.470591537717763,180.},{-14.842453559942024,190.},{-15.185537946620293,200.},{-15.50507451487766,210.},{-15.805477093216508,220.},{-16.359148622816097,240.},{-16.864221756309153,260.},{-17.331782147471895,280.},{-17.7704410644037,300.},{-18.1863994482277,320.},{-18.582846794542757,340.},{-18.964546221796557,360.},{-19.333726745661632,380.},{-19.69257556476376,400.},{-20.554367300484596,450.},{-21.37431184148772,500.},{-22.157071180737354,550.},{-22.89745771517206,600.},{-23.585866797897218,650.},{-24.206758461335397,700.},{-24.74733834618318,750.},{-25.200922702635545,800.},{-25.573825183196032,850.},{-25.880257267404012,900.},{-26.137443089588984,950.},{-26.360979711632908,1000.}}

Comment: another way to pull the data out: `Cases[chart, LineBox[__], Infinity] /. LineBox -> List`  -- note also  plots made by mathematica itself use `Line` instead of `LineBox`

Comment: ... and it seems if you need to play the copy paste game it gets turned back into a line so `Cases[<paste>,Line[__],Infinity]`

Comment: @george - also `Cases[chart, _LineBox, Infinity]` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Recycling an answer from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2420/363), this function stores up mouse point clicks in a variable `pts`.  You will need to combine your curve in the `Show` function, suitably scaled.  Here I just put in a sine plot.

It uses a dynamic module so the points will still be there when you save, close and reopen your notebook.

```
CreateDistribution[] := 
 DynamicModule[{savepts = {{-1, -1}}}, 
  Dynamic[EventHandler[
    Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 7}], 
     ListPlot[pts, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 5}}]], 
    "MouseDown" :> (savepts = 
       pts = DeleteCases[
         Append[pts, MousePosition["Graphics"]], {-1, -1}])], 
   Initialization :> (pts = savepts)]]

CreateDistribution[]
```

[image]

```
pts
```

> {{0.371185, 0.357737}, {0.859027, 0.779375}, {1.55898, 
>     1.01471}, {2.36498, 0.661709}, {2.95887, 
>     0.161626}, {3.55277, -0.358067}, {4.10424, -0.799316}, {4.91024, -0.985622}, {5.6314, -0.573789}, {6.20409, -0.142345}, {6.71314, 
>     0.367543}}

Comment: I'm not looking to extract rough approximations of co-ordinates from my clicking on the plot. I'm rather hoping to find the EXACT co-ordinates of a graph of an UNKNOWN equation (density vs altitude of heterosphere, in case you're wondering - wolfram alpha this if you can be bothered). Just to reiterate my original post, if you keep clicking the graph, a sequence of co-ordinates of that graph are shown. Is it not possible to get the co-ordinates of those points? I just feel like Mathematica would support this functionality.